# change all file names (prefix to postfix)

Tags: files, rename, batch-rename

I have a directory containing thousands of files with names

```
t_00xx_000xxx.png
```

I want to change their names to `00xx_000xxx_t.png`

so take the prefix and put it as a postfix, can this be done in only one command

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/prename.1p.html) command:

First check what *would* be done (by suppliying `-n`). If it looks good, drop the `-n` and run again:

```
rename -n 's/t_(.+)\.png$/$1_t.png/' *.png  # check only
rename    's/t_(.+)\.png$/$1_t.png/' *.png  # actually rename the files
```

Comment: `/train03_B> rename -n 's/t_(.+)\.png$/$1_t.png/' *.png

rename: invalid option -- 'n'

Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...

Rename files.

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on the target of symlinks

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).`

Answer (score 1):

If the prefix is separated by an underscore (`_`), you can do the following:

```
rename -n 's/^([^_]*)_(.*)\.(.*)$/$2_$1.$3/' file(s)
```

It will work with any prefix and any extension.

Remove the `-n` to perform the rename if you're happy with the result.

---

**Explanation:**

- `s/search_pattern/replace_pattern/`

Search pattern:

- `^` - Match the beginning of the file name
- `([^_]*)` - Match any character that is not an underscore `[^_]*` and capture it as `$1` `(...)`
- `_` - Match the first underscore
- `(.*)\.(.*)` - Match anything `.*` before and after the last `.` and capture it as `$2` and `$3`. The `.` must be escaped because it is a special character in Regex --> `\.`
- `$` - Match the end of the line

Replace pattern:

- `$2_$1.$3` - "Filename_Prefix.Extension" from the search pattern captures.

Comment: `/train03_B> rename -n 's/t_(.+)\.png$/$1_t.png/' *.png rename: invalid option -- 'n' Usage: rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>... Rename files. Options: -v, --verbose explain what is being done -s, --symlink act on the target of symlinks -h, --help display this help and exit -V, --version output version information and exit For more details see rename(1).`

Comment: you're using Ubuntu?

Comment: SuSE SLES12 SP2

Comment: then why do you ask this question on ask**ubuntu** ?

Comment: you have another `rename` tool. that is why it does not work for you

Comment: oh I thought I posted in unix/linux .. I am so sorry for that
it's a mistake, I will move the question there

Comment: ah yes this is for sure the problem @RoVo

Comment: try `prename` instead of `rename`, maybe you have that installed.

Comment: but I remember I used the `rename` here before, but maybe this tool is without the `-n` flag

Comment: not installed unfortunately, and I don't have sudo rights for its installation

Comment: if I am sure with your answer, I can run it directly without the `-n`, and it will work

Comment: no, your rename tool works differently.

Comment: nevermind, good luck at unix&linux SE

Comment: is there a way to move the question there ? or do I have to post a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

`mmv` (available from the `universe` repository) is nice for this kind of thing, where simple shell globs rather than regular expression can do the job

Ex.

```
mmv -n -- '*_*_*.png' '#2_#3_#1.png'
t_00xx_000xxx.png -> 00xx_000xxx_t.png
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it's working right.

Comment: `mmv: command not found`

Comment: @MostafaHussein Then do `sudo apt install mmv`

Comment: i have no sudo rights