# Remove characters from multiple file names

Tags: rename

I have loads of files with file names that I need to simplify. I need to keep everything before the first _ , and the _R1/R2 bit.

```
A10_S65_L001_R1_001.fastq  
A8_S49_L001_R2_001.fastq   
B7_S42_L001_R1_001.fastq   
C5_S27_L001_R2_001.fastq   
F4_S22_L001_R1_001.fastq   
G2_S7_L001_R2_001.fastq    
H1_S165_L001_R1_001.fastq
A10_S65_L001_R2_001.fastq  
A9_S57_L001_R1_001.fastq   
B7_S42_L001_R2_001.fastq   
C6_S35_L001_R1_001.fastq   
F4_S22_L001_R2_001.fastq   
G3_S15_L001_R1_001.fastq   
H1_S165_L001_R2_001.fastq
```

So the first example would be ---->  `A10_R1.fastq`

I've been able to use `rename 's/*L001//' *L001*.fastq` to remove parts of it but it gets complicated as the length of characters before the first _ varies. I'd really appreciate some help!

Thank you!

Comment: `rename  -e 's/^[^_]*_//' -e 's/_R[12]_001.fastq$//' *`

Comment: I'd probably use `mmv` for this - see similar answer at [change all file names (prefix to postfix)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061457/178692)

Comment: Related: [How to rename all files in a folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165503)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways ... I'll list three ways below for example.

#### First way

Using [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mmv.1.html):

```
mmv -n -- '*_*_*_*_*.fastq' '#1_#4.fastq'
```

`'*_*_*_*_*.fastq'` will work on all files with an extension of `.fastq` in the current working directory splitting the file name into parts(where `*` is) by the specified delimiter i.e. `_` ... These parts are then called by number `#`(the first one being `#1`) to form the new filename i.e. `'#1_#4.fastq'` ... The `-n` option is for dry-run(simulation but no actual renaming is done) ... Remove `-n` when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

#### Second way

Using [`rename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html):

```
rename  -n 's/^([^.]+)\_([^.]+)\_([^.]+)\_([^.]+)\_([^.]+)\.fastq$/$1_$4.fastq/' *.fastq
```

Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165673/968501)(The **explanation** part) for explanation on hwo it works and [this link](https://regex101.com/r/F03ahv/1) for regular expressions break down ... The `-n` option is for dry-run(simulation but no actual renaming is done) ... Remove `-n` when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

#### Third way

Using [`mv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mv.1.html) with [bash arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) in a [bash for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html) in a bash shell script file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.fastq; do # Work on files with ".fastq" extention in the current working directory assigning their namese one at a time(for each loop run) to the fariable "$f"
    IFS='_.' read -r -a array <<< "$f" # Split filename into parts/elements by "_" and "." and read the elements into an array
    f1="${array[0]}_${array[3]}.${array[5]}" # Set the new filename in the variable "$f1" by sellecting certain array elements and adding back "_" and "."
    echo mv -- "$f" "$f1" # Renaming dry-run(simulation) ... Remove "echo" when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.
done
```

or in a bash command string:

```bash
bash -c `for f in *.fastq; do IFS='_.' read -r -a array <<< "$f"; f1="${array[0]}_${array[3]}.${array[5]}"; echo mv -- "$f" "$f1"; done`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! mmv seems very straight forward but I don't have it installed and don't want to wait for my administrator, rename worked very well. Thanks again.